# How to change the space margin in a menu?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, qt5

The code below creates `QMenu` with the font set to be quite small. I would like to go ahead and reduce the distance (a "context margin" or "spacing")) between the individual Submenus names (or the Action names). How to change the submenus spacing?

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu, QApplication
app = QApplication([])

menu = QMenu()
font = menu.font()
font.setPointSize(10)
menu.setFont(font)
for i in range(5):
    submenu = menu.addMenu('Submenu %04d' % i)
    submenu.setFont(font)
    for n in range(10):
        action = submenu.addAction('Action %04d' % n)

menu.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I believe the left margin is left for icons, toggle markers, etc. I'm not sure whether it can be reduced by style modifications. The menu icon size _might_ have an influence...

Comment: You could show an image of what you want to get to understand you better.

Comment: I would like to reduce the blank space between each Action so they are listed "denser"...

Comment: app.setStyleSheet('QMenu::item{spacing:0px;margin:0px;}') may make them slightly smaller